# Is there some form of auto indentation mode in OpenModelica OMEdit?

Tags: openmodelica

I'm new to OpenModelica. I'm an experienced programmer (C++ and Octave) and I tried to use OMShell but it is quite hard to me, because I find that it gives very little feedback when errors are produced. So I switched to the GUI version (OMEdit). I can't find an auto-indentation feature, i.e. I would like to select all or part of the code and have the editor to reformat the code for me, like the TAB key en Emacs. Is there something like that?

TIA, Mario

Answer (score 0):

No, OMEdit doesn't have any auto formatter.

Adeel.